# posting pic with python with twitpic fails

Tags: python, twitter, twitpic

I am trying to find a way to post a pic with tweet via twitpic.com. There is a python solution called twitpic:
https://github.com/macmichael01/python-twitpic

I have installed this on a linux server, but I am new to python I am afraid.

usage: twitpic [-h] [-m MESSAGE]
               consumer_key consumer_secret access_token service_key file

Python-TwitPic commandline utility.

However, when I use my credentials it says:
twitpic -m bomengids xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx............... T7hDxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.............Q 324319099-QYRpFFkAtPskJKh.......... bb7c3d68acb6d9............. /root/pics/1.jpg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twitpic", line 23, in 
    service_key = opts.service_key,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twitpic/twitpic2.py", line 139, in **init**
    self.access_token = oauth.OAuthToken.from_string(access_token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth/oauth.py", line 142, in from_string
    key = params['oauth_token'][0]
KeyError: 'oauth_token'

what does this mean? How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I am beginning to think this twitpic lib is not for the latest twitter api?

Answer (score 0):

The README.md file (https://github.com/macmichael01/python-twitpic/blob/master/README.md) says 
""*Command also requires python-2.7 to use.*". From the traceback I see your using Python version 2.6. This could be the problem.